# Android bitmap image size

Tags: android, bitmap, size

I am downloading images from web and i use Gallery widget to display the images.

If the downloaded image size is huge, my application crashes with the below log.

```
"E/GraphicsJNI( 3378): VM won't let us allocate 5591040 bytes"
```

I want to scale down the downloaded image size only when the image size is more to an extent that it will crash the app. I have written the code to scale down the image size but i am not sure how to find the bitmap size so i can decide on whether to scale or not

```
   BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   o.inSampleSize = 2;
   Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,null,o);
   Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bit, 200, 200, true);
   bit.recycle();
   return scaled;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds) field of `BitmapFactory.Options` to get bitmap dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

To get bitmap dimensions, you can simply use:

To get height -> bitmap.getHeight()
To get width -> bitmap.getWidth()